# Diferenciar columnas usando inner join

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo este código:

```
  $getAlumno = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM alumnos INNER JOIN modulos ON alumnos.nivel=modulos.ID WHERE alumnos.ID='$login'") or die ('error al obtener datos de alumno');
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($getAlumno,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Mi problema es que en `alumnos` tengo el campo nombre que muestra el nombre de usuario:

```
<?php echo $row['nombre'];?>
```

y mi tabla de modulos tiene el mismo nombre de columna:

```
<?php echo $row['nombre'];?>
```

Entonces cuando quiero mostrar la información de nombre del alumno me manda el nombre del modulo. ¿Cómo puedo diferenciar esta información?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando usas dos columnas de tablas diferentes que tienen nombres iguales, en la Select es conveniente darles un alias:

```
$getAlumno = mysqli_query(
    $con,
    "SELECT *,
        modulos.nombre as nom_modulo,
        alumnos.nombre as nom_alumno 
    FROM alumnos 
    INNER JOIN modulos ON alumnos.nivel=modulos.ID
    WHERE alumnos.ID='$login'"
) or die ('error al obtener datos de alumno');

  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($getAlumno,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Me funciono perfecto!

Answer (score -1):

Necesitas todos los campos de ambas tablas? Porque yo te recomendaría que le agregues un alias a cada campo y así evitas el conflicto de datos.